# Should I add profession name with my name in resume?

Tags: cv

[This is a clarification question on whether I should do this or not]

Should I add Dr., Engg. like salutation in front of my name in my resume. For example, if John Smith passed BSc in Mechanical Engineering, should he write Engineer John Smith in his resume or he should write only John Smith?

Comment: I don't even think the Germans do that, but maybe someone does.

Comment: I think Portuguese people do it.  At least I assume Enginheiro is not my landlord's first name :)

Comment: @StrongBad: "Dipl.-Ing" is certainly still in use, even if it will disappear more and more now that people only get bachelor/master... That said, once you get a Dr. I think it's rare to add the field when using it as a title.

Comment: Dipl-Ing is the official title given by the university (otherwise you are not allowed to use it, at least in Germany), much like Dr. phil. or Dr. rer. nat. It is not including actual information about the profession that is more than a hint in the general direction. (Some universities definitely hand out different titles than others for basically the same field of study.)

Comment: @skymningen: isn't the "Dr. Engg." in question also the title given by the university? I was assuming it would be the equivalent of German "Dr. Ing."...

Comment: @nengel It might be. But then it is not a profession name, it is an academic degree, which changes the meaning of the question. A degree is something defined, that you can prove you achieved, while the name of a profession is often less defined. (I can fairly easily start a business as a self-made interiour designer, that does not make me a Master of Arts, though.)

Answer (score 1):

There are two different types of "titles" you could add to your name, and it is not quite clear which you mean.

1. **The degree you achieved.** Heading your resume with "John Smith, PhD" or "Dr. John Smith" is something people do in places where degrees are valued, like Germany. (And also of course on academic CVs.) It might come across poorly in other areas, e.g. I get the impression that US people think it looks "stuck up" or "full of yourself". For a Bachelor's degree, it would be odd to use "John Smith, BSc" simply because so many people have one, so there's nothing special about it.
2. **The profession.** Some professions are regulated, like in your example "Engineer". In many countries it is illegal to call yourself an Engineer unless you are registered with a professional association that regulates the exercise of your profession. (Acquiring the degree is not always enough.) In those cases, if you are in fact a registered Engineer, writing whatever your local equivalent of "Ir John Smith" is on your resume can be a quick signal that you fulfil this requirement for a job that you are applying for. If your profession is not regulated, there is probably no good reason to put it in your name - your job is whatever the person you are trying to get to hire you says it is, and it's probably best not to contradict them ;)

Comment: It is not "stuck up" in the US to add it to your resume. The resume's goal is to convey your professional qualifications for career purposes. It is seen as stuck up to use it in a social context where your career isn't important.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the highly conditional tone of the advice on this subject - IF it's a doctorate-level degree AND it's a requirement for the position AND no other credentials are more relevant ONLY THEN may you list it - made it sound to me like the default assumption is that you're being pretentious...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably highly culture-specific, but I (Austria) would do so: The headline with my name would contain all my titles.
(Here, I assumed you asked about including titles - I don't understand what you mean by "Engg.". I also would not write "Engineer John Smith" but "John Smith, BSc" unlesss Engineer is the title John Smith is legally allowed to wear.)